# Spring Tool Suite org.joda cannot be resolved in Gradle project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I have started a Gradle project with Spring Tool Suite. Following this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/ it indicates that I should add the org.joda dependency in my build.gradle file, import the dependency in the class, build the package, and then it should be available to use. However, when I do this and re-build the project and run it, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    LocalTime cannot be resolved to a type
    LocalTime cannot be resolved to a type

    at firstGradleProject.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:7)
```

My dependencies appear to be set up appropriately:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.2')
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
}
```

How can I import this dependency in my Gradle Spring project and get it to compile?

My entire build.gradle file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-gradle'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.2')
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
}
```

Comment: it sounds like the IDE shows some errors about compilation problems due to missing types, right? Did you install the Buildship extension to your STS installation (which is the Gradle support for Eclipse)?

Comment: did you try to execute a Gradle build outside your IDE, e.g. in command line ( git bash or MS Powershell for example) , and what is the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes

Joda time support is deprecated in favour of java.time.